# Is there any way to print letters with star pattern * on the terminal?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

I've scoured various sources, but unfortunately, I haven't stumbled upon a way that fits my requirements for integration into my Node.js project. Any insights or recommendations would be invaluable at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a npm modules available for printing letters and some shapes with star patterns on the terminal.

One popular module I have used for my project called "any-pattern"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-pattern